# Distinguish b/w captured `this` members from captured variables in C++ lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm wondering about captures in lambdas in C++.
I know that lambda expression is just "generator" for some functor class.
I'm wondering how compiler does distinguish between members from captured 'this' from members of generated functor class?

And, second question:

In example below `a_` from capture list shadows `A::a_`. Is this behavior described in standard? I can't find answer for that anywhere.

```
class A {
    int a_ = 0;
public:
    void sth() {
        auto l = [this, a_=1](int a) { a_ = a; };
        l(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: this won't compile . `a_` is immutable because the lambda is not marked `mutable`

Comment: @RichardHodges I know, it's just example for ilustrating problem

Answer (score 1):

breaking it down (and fixing the bug):

```
class A {
    int a_ = 0;  // this is A::a_
public:
    void sth() {
        auto l = 
          [
              this,  // A::sth::lambda::l::_this 
              a_=a_   // A::sth::lambda::l::a_ = A::a_  // because the lambda's a_ does not exist until it's defined.
          ](int a) mutable 
          { 
              a_ = a;  // A::sth::lambda::l::a_ = argument a 
          };
        l(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: so, if I understand corectly:

when compiler find some variable (a_ here) in lambda body, it search it in body as local variable or as passed parameter, if it not found it then search this var in lambda captures (lambda 'members') and if there is no such lambda members it tries to get (A::sth::lambda::l::)_this->a_ , is that correct ? And this is defined rule, yes ?

Comment: @J.Klimczak in this case we are explicitly capturing this (A's this) and A's a_. We are storing them in the lambda's _this and the lambda's a_. If we had also specified & in the capture block. When referencing variables in code in the lambda's definition, the lambda's names are searched first, then any outer scope.